# Hard-limit quota not enforced

Tags: opensuse, quota

I have configured my box to allow a certain user up to 2GB of storage thanks to `quota`.

I *think* I have enabled it correctly. `/etc/fstab` shows `usrquota,grpquota`, `quotaon` says everything is fine **but** I have been able to violate the quota today.

From SSH, I sudo-ed into that user and tried to create a 4GB file

```
# sudo -u targetuser bash ##the user cannot use SSH
targetuser@host:~> dd if=/dev/zero of=prova.bin count=4096 bs=1048536
sda1: warning, user block quota exceeded.
^C^C3592+0 records in
3592+0 records out
3766341312 bytes (3,8 GB) copied, 333,72 s, 11,3 MB/s
```

`edquota -u targetuser` shows (after I deleted the file)

```
Disk quotas for user targetuser (uid 1006):
  Filesystem                   blocks       soft       hard     inodes     soft     hard
  /dev/sda1                    181200    2097072   22097072      10230        0        0
```

I'lve also been able to write a new file before deleting the elephant.

The question is tremendously simple: why didn't Linux stop dd from writing more instead of just warning?

What can I do to raise an error when a user attempts to write more than he's allowed to?